# How to keep divs from overlapping/moving/making my page look ugly when resizing width and/or height of browser window

Tags: html, css, resize, margin, padding

So I'm trying to be able to keep everything where it is even on a a window re size.. an example of what I wish for is similar to face book's registration page (or any page on facebook for that matter... everything gets hidden behind the browser as i minimize its width). I've included two links one a jfiddle and second an actual test page:

https://jsfiddle.net/0nskvmjc/

http://sushionfir3.byethost7.com/test/register.php

here's the html for my own registration page

```
<!--background image-->
<style type="text/css">
  body {
   background-image: url(bg/bg.jpg);
   background-size: cover;
}
</style>
<!---->

<body>
<!--top green transparent bar-->
  <nav class="bar"></nav>

 <div class="logo">
  <img src="img/logo.png" height=90px>
 </div>
 <br />

 <div class="login">Log in</div>
  <div class="signin">
   <form class="pure-form" action="#" method="post">
    <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="Email">
    <input class="input" type="password" placeholder="Password">
    <button type="submit" class="button-sign pure-button">Sign in</button>
   </form>
<!---->

<!--registration form start-->
 <div id="reg_border"></div>
 <div class="reg_form">
  <h2 id="register_right">Registration is free and easy!</h2>
 <div class="form_inputs">
 <form class="pure-form" action="#" method="POST">
   <input class="input" type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First name" />
   <input class="input" type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Last name" /><br />
   <input class="input" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" size="49" /><br />
   <div class="space">
   <input class="input" type="text" name="remail" placeholder="Please re-enter your Email" size="49" /><br />
   </div>
   <div class="space">
   <input class="input" type="password" name="npassword" placeholder="New password" size="49" />
   </div>
   <p class="birthdate">Date of birth</p>
  <div class="birthday_options">
   <select class="months">
     <option value="jan">Jan</option>
     <option value="feb">Feb</option>
     <option value="mar">Mar</option>
     <option value="apr">Apr</option>
     <option value="may">May</option>
     <option value="jun">Jun</option>
     <option value="jul">Jul</option>
     <option value="aug">Aug</option>
     <option value="sep">Sep</option>
     <option value="oct">Oct</option>
     <option value="nov">Nov</option>
     <option value="dec">Dec</option>
   </select>
   <select class="days">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
    <option value="13">13</option>
    <option value="14">14</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
    <option value="16">16</option>
    <option value="17">17</option>
    <option value="18">18</option>
    <option value="19">19</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="21">21</option>
    <option value="22">22</option>
    <option value="23">23</option>
    <option value="24">24</option>
    <option value="25">25</option>
    <option value="26">26</option>
    <option value="27">27</option>
    <option value="28">28</option>
    <option value="29">29</option>
    <option value="30">30</option>
    <option value="31">31</option>
  </select>
   <input class="input" type="text" name="year" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" size="10" />
  </div><!--birthdaymonths-->
  <p class="sex">Gender</p>
   <div class="genders">
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="1">Male</input>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="2">Female</input>
   </div>
     <button id="signup" type="submit" class="button-sign pure-button">Sign up!</button>
   </form>
  </div><!--form_inputs-->
 </div><!--reg_form-->
</body>
```

and here's the css for it

```
.bar {
      width: 100%;
      height: 90px;
      background-color: rgba(0,160,135,0.4);
}

.logo {
      margin-top: -88px;
      padding-left: 50px;
}

.login {
      text-align: right;
      margin-top: -100px;
      margin-right: 486px;
      color: white;
}

.signin {
      text-align: right;
      padding-right: 50px;
      padding-top: 5px
}

#reg_border {
      background: rgba(0,160,135,0.4);
      width: 32%;
      height: 70%;
      margin: 6% 1% 3% auto;
      -webkit-border-radius: 70px;
      -moz-border-radius: 70px;
      -o-border-radius: 70px;
}

.reg_form {
      text-align: right;
      padding-right: 24px;
      line-height: 48px;
      margin-top: -525px;
}

.input {
      line-height: 20px
}

#register_right {
      padding-right: 29px;
      padding-top: 30px
}

.birthdate {
      margin: auto 310px auto 100px;
}

.birthday_options {
      margin: -10px 125px auto 100px;
}

.sex {
      margin: -5px 345px auto 100px;
}

.genders {
      margin: -20px 265px auto auto;
}

.space {
      margin-top: 4px
}

#signup {
      width: 13em;
      margin: 2px 95px auto auto
}
```

Thank you in advance. I've tried looking up these questions but none of the answers on other people's questions seem to work for me.. maybe the issue is within what I've already coded and adding extra bits of code isn't going to help or MAYBE it is, I'm not sure haha.  Thank you again.

Comment: it would be good to add a jsfiddle link so people can edit it with updated answer

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/0nskvmjc/

Comment: http://sushionfir3.byethost7.com/test/register.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I GOT IT! For me, adding a min and max width of 1366px did the trick!

```
<style type="text/css">
body, html {
  background-image: url(bg/bg.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-width: 1366px;
  margin: auto auto;
  max-width: 1366px;
 }
</style>
```

I'm somewhat satisfied with its current result, however, still open for a better way :)